# Staking & slashing between Relay Chains

Tags: staking

How do we stake token TA (minted on one relay chain, say RA) on another relay chain, say RB, such that RB can slash TA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One chain would have to give authority to do so to the other.

They would be exchanging messages and have a way to make sure that they are really getting the message from the other chain. Since they would be under different security umbrellas, you would need a mechanism like light clients to verify the information from the other chain.

If you want to dig deeper into this topic, you might want to take a look at BridgeHub, which is currently being developed and will also connect Polkadot and Kusama.

Comment: Indeed, you would need something like `fn slash` with a `SlashOrigin`. Then in the runtime of the chain on which you want the slashing to occur, you will set that origin to `MultiLocation { parents: 2, interior: X*(PathToSlashAuthority) }`. There will indeed be some examples in the next 6 months using Bridge Hub.

Comment: This has been discussed in the Polkadot forum here: https://forum.polkadot.network/t/allow-restaking-of-relay-chain-stake-through-custom-slashing-privileges/347